# Changing value from the filter list in excel

Tags: excel, filter, vba

I have two sheet. sheet1 is dashboard and sheet2 is raw data.
From the sheet1 I am using auto-filter respect of some input.
Is there possible to change the filtered value(from sheet1). It should affect sheet2 also.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not understandable. I realize that English is not your first language (not mine, either) and that it is difficult to explain what you would like to achieve. Still, try to provide some more information. You could post a sample file on one of the free file sharing services. Explain in detail what you start with and what you want as a result. Explain the logic that must be applied to get from one to the other.

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/441626/test.xlsm Pleas find the above like for the example file. Here, sheet1 contain source value, and filtering from sheet2. Is there is possible to change and save from sheet2. It should also reflect on sheet1(source data)

Comment: The data in both sheets is the same. What to you want to do? What is the expected output? What is the logic in words?

Comment: This is what i understand: he filters sheet no 1 - if a cell value in sheet 1 is changed the change should be adopted to his raw data - am i getting this right?

Comment: @therak Yes, you're right.

Comment: if you have some id in your data, you will be able to utilize the Worskheet_Change Event and change the value in the raw data sheet via code - search for the id in the raw data sheet and apply the change.

Comment: @therak Can you please give example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested here some sample code:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'check for first row - in example first row is filter row
    'check for first column - column 1 could be your id column
    Dim rawRange As Range
    If Target.Row > 1 And Target.Column > 1 Then
        'Search for the ID in your rawData sheet - in this case Tabelle2 Column A
        Set rawRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("A:A").Find(What:=ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value)
        If Not rawRange Is Nothing Then
            'here you can work with offset to find the correct column - of course the columns have to be the same in sheet 1 and 2
            rawRange.Offset(0, Target.Column - 1).Value = Target.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Remember its just an example but it basically works if you create a new workbook and adjust the Worksheet names. The Worksheet Change Event code has to be pasted into the first sheet.

If you have any further questions just ask

Edit:

Link to [ExampleFile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19239371/excelproblem.xlsm)